# Extracting p-values using corrr package in R

Tags: r, correlation, p-values

I'm performing correlation analysis using the corrr package in R, but I'm unable to extract the p values. Does anyone know how to get the p values in corrr package in R?

Comment: If one of the solutions works for you, you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking at some of the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrr/index.html).

As far as I can tell, the intention of the package is to visualize and organize correlation coefficient estimates. It does not seem that the author of the package has any interest in p-value estimation.

If you are interested in computing p-values, I would suggest using a different tool, such as the builtin `cor.test()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [suggested workaround](https://github.com/tidymodels/corrr/issues/29):

- Generate a p-value table using one of these tools:

  - `RcmdrMisc::rcorr.adjust()`
  - `psych::corr.test()`

Then use `corrr:as_cordf()` to generate the tidy dataframe with the same structure as a regular corrr correlation table.

Personally, I have used the `Hmisc::rcorr()` package, and it works well:

```
Hmisc::rcorr() %>% `[[`('P') %>% corrr::as_cordf()
```

Comment: got it. thank you so much

Comment: I have since used this solution in my own work and I confirm that it works well.